# HttpClient is sending extra cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, httpclient, fiddler, uwp

Running a UWP app*

So I have an HttpClient and it's associated handler. I am making a request to a website, passing in specified headers, and using a specified CookieContainer, which is empty at the beginning of the request.

When I send the request, Fiddler shows extra cookies being sent that I have not added. Where are they coming from?

```
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();                
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler( );
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
handler.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
handler.Proxy = null;
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler as HttpClientHandler))
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    String loginUrl = Const.BUNGIE_LOGIN_URI + (provider == Const.XBOX_PLATFORM ? Const.XBOX_LOGIN : Const.PS_LOGIN);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(loginUrl);
    //client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 450);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "http://www.bungie.net");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", Const.USERAGENT);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-Key", Const.X_API_KEY);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");
    handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
    response.ReadCookies(); //adds cookies to cookieJar
 }
```

[What fiddler shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLmDe.png)

Now, as the associated `CookieContainer` is empty before the request is made, where are these cookies coming from? Are they accessible? If I wanted the values from them, how would I obtain them?

Edit: Where are they being added to my HttpClient request from? Does HttpClient have a common CookieContainer / cache? I have two separate HttpClient instances, and when Client (A) makes a request, it received a "set-cookie" header back, setting a "bungled" cookie.

Later on, a separate instance of HttpClient, Client (B), makes a request to the same website, sending the cookie set within Client (A).

I did not explicitly append this cookie to Client (B)'s request, so how is it being added?

Comment: What is `cookieJar`, how is it created?

Comment: Also, as you are explicitly setting the proxy to null, how re you capturing the data with Fiddler?

Comment: Its a CookieContainer. Updating code to reflect

Comment: @DavidG should I not be able to? I am able to see the request if that line is there or not.

Comment: Cookies being sent are server side function.  When you ask what are these cookies, the answer should be seen by running Fiddler or wireshark to the same end point, this would prove it's a server side thing.  This means the answer is related to the content being rendered in the page.  For example there could be a reference to Google Analytics or other 3rd party things which set the "extra" cookies.

Comment: I am not asking why I am getting the cookies from the server, I am asking how they are being appended to my client's request without me explicitly appending them. It appears HttpClient is sharing a common container across separate HttpClient instances, so when I obtain a cookie within one client, it is being shared to another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows 10 build 10240, `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` is a wrapper on top of `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` ([more info here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/07/28/net-networking-apis-for-uwp-apps.aspx)), and so, cookies now work  little bit different.

To delete those extra cookies, you will need to delete the cookies using a `HttpCookieManager`:

```
HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
HttpCookieManager cookieManager = filter.CookieManager;
foreach (HttpCookie cookie in cookieManager.GetCookies(uri))
{
    cookieManager.DeleteCookie();
}
```