# HttpClient is sending additional Cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, dotnet-httpclient, .net-core-3.1

With .NET Core 3.1 DI, I use an HttpClient instance inside an Azure Function to send data to an external API.

```
var clientRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, clientConfig.BaseURL + RequestParam);

string payloadBody = GenerateLoginPayload(clientConfig.Username, clientConfig.Password);
clientRequest.Content = new StringContent(payloadBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
clientRequest.Headers.Clear();

var response = await _api.SendAsync(clientRequest);
```

As you can see, I even cleared the `clientRequest` Headers. However, checking on Fiddler, it is still sending extra Cookie Headers. This is messing up our requests, as to the API, no past Cookies must be sent.

```
Cookie: KEY_PHPSESSID=HehRVwcsmiUmoxO4zYaOpO1B9hm%2BfAK9igvuRw4YjgA%3D%3AJ7Bgip94EQjfJ%2FSt5RcnFTY3jcZ%2FlChCoyK54v%2Fu%2FJI%3D
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 87
```

**My question is, what is adding that extra Cookie header value, and how can I clear or remove it?**

I also checked this [SO question about extra cookies being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849577/httpclient-is-sending-extra-cookies) which is similar to my situation, but t does not seem to apply to Azure Functions and .NET Core, as I do not have any reference to `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`

This is also how I registered my HttpClient, and the `_api.SendAsync()` is reused multiple times across multiple endpoints, and it's possible that the Cookie originated from a previous call. How do I ensure the Cookies don't bleed to other Requests?

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IApiCaller, ApiCaller>()
  .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false })
  .AddPolicyHandler(HttpRetryPolicies.RetryWithJitter());
```

Comment: Adding `UseCookies = false` like you did, fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a DefaultRequestHeader of HttpClient itself.

You could try `_api.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();`

Comment: I have already tried this one as well. Still the same issue. I even tried a version of my code where I use a  Static instance of the `HttpClient`, and cleared the Headers the same way, and the Cookie is still being sent.

Comment: Have you try creating instance of `HttpClient` from `HttpClientFactory` instead of instance from DI?

Comment: We were originally using that pattern. However, we occasionally get issues with Dryloc and Disposed scopes that we moved away from that pattern for now. But I do believe that the code should be able to remove the extra headers regardless of the DI pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint before the request and check the contents of

```
clientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.GetCookies()
```

If the cookie is in there, it might get set in the implementation of your `ApiCaller`. If there are no cookies there, it might be set by a setting/proxy in Azure

Comment: No cookies, up to the `SendAsync()` method. That's why it was hard to track as it was not showing in Debug locally, but is very visible with Fiddler.